# Failing to read array data from a plist - (null) ejected

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsdictionary

I am currently trying to get data out of a plist.

It basically looks like that:

```
plist called 'woerter'  
  -> Root key of type Dictionary  
    -> woerter key of type Array  
      -> various Items of type String with string Values
```

When I now try to read a random string from it, I only get a (null) expression

```
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString * finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"woerter.plist"];
NSDictionary * plistData = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath] retain];
NSArray * array = [plistData valueForKey:@"woerter"];
NSString * string = [array objectAtIndex:arc4random() %110];
NSLog(@"stringtest %@", string);
```

But all i get is

> 2010-02-28 23:01:58.911
>   TypeFast[5606:a0f] stringtest (null)

It is not a problem with arcrandom either since objectAtIndex:2 returns the same.

Where is the problem?

Thank you (:

Comment: You need to step through this code and find out where it's not working Any of your methods could be failing silently, returning null, and then cascading through to present a NULL to the final assignment. This is what gdb is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to alloc the NSDictionary and the NSArray, so the array and dictionary can not save the values.

Comment: Eh? The questioner is creating an NSDictionary from a file, so there is no need to alloc one, and is obtaining the array from the dictionary. There are a couple of reasons why this could fail, but not sending an `alloc` message is not one of them.